# Is JAVA knowledge must for Endeca Commerce Course

Tags: endeca, commerce

Do I need to know java to do Endeca commerce. And if yes can someone guide me to what extent of Java should I know, also if you could provide from where could I learn Java only for endeca. Dont want to learn the ADVANCE JAVA. So please guide me...

Comment: No. There are .NET APIs available for Endeca too. If you want to use the JAVA APIs, good knowledge is advisable.

Comment: Thanks radimpe, I was going to join training of Endeca commerce. So wanted to be sure if it is needed I should get some knowledge of it as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some different way to work with Endeca solution:

1. Working just settings things and pages as Experience Manager, Stop Words, using the Workbench website (Workbench is part of the Endeca solution) **(Zero knowledge in Java is needed.)**
2. Working in the Baseline point, when you need to provider some ETL workflow to get data from some dataset with Products and Attributes,...  The important thing at this point is to know better the component involved in the solution and how the components working together. (http://www.oracle.com/us/solutions/ent-performance-bi/oeid-tech-overview-1674380.pdf) **(There is some Spring java code but the AppConfig.xml from Endeca the only I believe if you have some basic java logic, you can understand the Scripts set)**
3. Just consuming data from some presented Endeca solution. In this points, you are working as a client and there are some API that can be helpful for you (java: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28913_02/ContentAssemblerJava.212/pdf/CADevGuideJava.pdf , .NET: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28914_01/RADdotNET.213/pdf/RADToolkitNET.pdf). **(If you will consume the Endeca as a Java client, at this point you just need to know the Java API)**